# OData v4: how to make $select work on bound functions

Tags: .net, odata

Using oData v4 (specifically Microsoft.AspNet.Odata 5.3.0 and Microsoft.Odata.Core 6.7.0), my query operators, in particular $select, are getting ignored for functions even though I've declared the functions as IsComposable = true.

Any suggestions how to make this scenario work? I’m interested primarily in $filter and $select.

-Max

**Details** (based on FunctionSamples within https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples)

**Attempted Query:** http://localhost:9010/odata/Products/Default.Top10()?$select=Name

**Expected response (excerpt)**

```
{
Name: "Product 48"
}
```

**Actual response (excerpt)**

```
{
Id: 48,
Name: "Product 48",
Price: 986.2794056470876
}
```

**Function Declaration:**

```
// Function bound to a collection
// Returns the top 10 product, a collection
productType.Collection
   .Function("Top10")
   .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Product>("Products")
   .IsComposable = true;
```

**Controller:**

```
// Returns the top ten most expensive products
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Top10()
{
    var retval = _data.Values.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).Take(10).ToList();

    return Ok(retval);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I needed to mark the controller method as [EnableQuery].